# Are there advantages to using differential RS485-like communication between two MCUs using digital GPIOs only (without transceiver)?

Tags: gpio, rs485

I have two MCUs and two wires between then. Currently these wires are used as I2C and work well, but we expect bursts of noise and want to protect against it. I am thinking of converting from I2C to RS485 or similar, but we have no space nor money for a separate transceiver chip.

Would there be advantages to implementing differential RS485-like protocol using just two GPIOs on each side with no other parts (except, may be, clamping diodes)?

There was a similar question [Options for Differential transmission of digital signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/345369/options-for-differential-transmission-of-digital-signal) but that was for a high precision synchronization signal, while I only need relatively low speed communication.

Thank you

PS: I was asking about advantages of "differential" (or complementary) GPIO vs other single ended digital protocols, not about comparison of GPIO vs real analog differential transceivers. Unfortunately, most of the answers focused on the latter.

Comment: How do you intend to implement differential signaling on bare GPIOs?  What is the bit rate you hope to achieve?  How long is the signal path between the MCUs and what is the characteristic of the noise you expect to design against?

Comment: You can drive RS-485 with GPIO, but without a true differential receiver on the other end, much of the benefit is lost.

Comment: Why not uart? Are these chips on the same board?

Comment: @vir Modern MCUs, like STM32, have input/output channels, which allow you to generate almost any set of digital signals and record almost any signals.
So, generating 2 opposite signals is trivial and reading 2 signals is also easy, while checking for difference in software.

Comment: @Bryan "Why not UART?" - this is the gist of this question. I think that UART can be confused by a noise spike at the moment of sampling, but 2 opposite GPIOs should shift in the same direction and so their difference will remain 0. Is it right?
(By the way my wires will be a couple of feet long, in a coax cable, but very close to strong noise from motor/actuator wires).

Comment: It isn't RS485 without a proper 485 transceiver interface.

Comment: @Bryan - UART has nothing to do with whether the physical interface is '485, '422, or just plain LVTTL.

Comment: @SteveSh yeah that’s my bad, I always conflate uart in my head to be “uart straight from the pin”

Comment: We need some additional information in order to provide a proper assessment.  1) What is the distance between the two MCUs?  2) Are they in the same box, powered by the same power supplies? Or are they in different boxes with different power supplies?  3) What does your ground system look like? 4) What data rate do you need between the MCUs?

Comment: @SteveSh It is a tiny sensor/actuator tip at the end of 3 foot cable. Common power (1.8V), common ground, but a lot of noise from a high voltage/high current/high frequency actuator. It is not clear yet whether every wire will be in coax or not, but even coax may not protect from noise.
Note that I faced this question on different projects over the years, so it will be nice to have a more generic answer when CPUs can talk over digital and when transceiver is a must.

Comment: @jhnlmn - If your data rate is low enough, you might want to consider some form of ECC or FEC (Forward Error Correcting) on the I2C links. This can be done in firmware/software.

Comment: And of coax doesn't provide enough shielding, you might want to look at triax.

Comment: @SteveSh Our cable is super thin with many wires and very few choices are available. I2C is the worst protocol since it is weakly pulled and can misinterpret noise edges for clock cycle. So, I should, probably, use something UART-like. But ECC/FEC will not help me if UART bytes are erroneously triggered by noise spikes, which are misinterpreted as start bits and no valid bytes ever arrive. So, I should, probably, do some oversampling/debouncing. But the question remain: in addition to all of the above, will differential/complementary GPIOs offer any additional improvements?

Answer (score 5):

Using two IO ports to receive a "differential" signal is not the same as using a dedicated differential receiver. A differential receiver subtracts two voltages, on two conductors, both of which will have roughly the same noise induced upon them. The common noise will be mostly cancelled as a result of the subtraction. The subtraction is an *analogue* operation, which yields an analogue result. Only then is this result compared with some mid-level potential to determine the corresponding digital high or low value.

When you deliver two digital signals to an MCU, the digital conversion is performed on each, before the MCU can do any kind of noise removal via analogue subtraction. Noise immunity would be no better than sending two consecutive digital bits concurrently.

I assume your MCUs are separated by a significant distance, and if you can't use differential line drivers/receivers then your best bet is to wrap the single-ended signal carrying conductor inside a shield grounded at both ends, like coaxial cable. At low data rates over distances up to a couple of metres, you probably don't need to worry about termination. You definitely should consider error detection and correction in software.

Answer (score 2):

Without differential receiver (or at least something "better" than common GPIO) you won't get any real advantage.

When you have one signal connected to digital pin, from software point of view you have exactly two distinct states. You are reading either 0 or 1. And you have two faulty states (not counting burned MCU etc. :) ), signal sent as 0 being read as 1 and signal sent as 1 being sent as 0.

If you connect two pins in this "differential" (better say complementary) scheme, the four outcomes, two correct, two faulty, applies absolutely unchanged for each of these two inputs. And with same probabilities of bit-flips because each pin is connected and sensitive to disturbances independently of the other one.

Looking at the pair as whole, you only gain two extra input states for your software, namely seeing 11 or 00. In that case software knows the value is invalid, but has no way to correct the error (you do not know which bit was flipped).

So you gain some kind of error detection at the best. This could be nevertheless achieved in software only using CRC or other coding (i.e. hamming) giving not only detection but even error correction. Depending on the nature of your expected disturbances, data coding parameters can be tuned to provide likely better performance compared to adding second digital signal.

Comment: 1. What if I oversample? Say, 5 samples per bit? Would the extra complementary bit provide some advantage vs traditional FEC? 
2. In single ended UART the start bit is especially vulnerable - if noise keeps triggering false start bits, then no amount of CRC/FEC would help.
I thought that extra complementary bit together with oversampling may help detect/discard false start bits.

Comment: @jhnlmn Oversampling might help if you were sure that the aggressor signal was a little higher frequency than your clock rate since you could measure it and remove it. That's not too likely though, and you'd probably be better off just using a checksum or CRC.

Answer (score 1):

No, two GPIOs won't have the common mode rejection of a true differential receiver like RS-485 as each GPIO is measured against circuit GND and not against the complementary GPIO.

But it's a good idea to get rid of I2C for off-board communication in a noisy environment. One disadvantage of I2C - from a noise immunity perspective - is the high-impedance logic high ("driven" only by the pull up resistors). So any physical layer without a high-impedance logic state might be an improvement regarding noise immunity.

Answer (score 0):

The subtraction of the analog receiver is important for the noise reduction. But imho, the subtraction can be made in digital form as well.

Because the common mode noise will make both digital inputs 1 or 0 in the same time, while the transmitter will make them always different.

So, depending on the algorithms used, the noise can be detected and this way removed from the signal. But well, it is a matter of development. I have never hear about something like this implemented.

After all, the differential drivers are so cheap and solve the problem before the digital stages.

Comment: "I have never hear about something like this implemented".  That's probably because it cannot be guaranteed to work over the range of common mode voltages that a properly designed RS-485 (or '422 for that matter) interface can.

Comment: Yes, this was my idea (actually my coworker's idea) from the beginning. Question is whether it makes sense. Unfortunately, RS485 transceivers appear to be twice larger and twice more expensive than MCUs.

Comment: Some small MCUs do contain analog comparators, but usually without any hysteresis. Perhaps there's a way to configure them to serve as differential receivers.

Comment: @jhnlmn: Well, it highly depends on the algorithms used, the level of the noise and the communication speeds you need. But some (many) experiments are mandatory. If you have a time to work on it - try.

Comment: @Dave Tweed Yes, modern MCUs often have differential ADC and comparators, but the current question is specifically about GPIOs. I guess that would be another question whether differential ADC or comparator can replace real differential receiver or not.